# Books/monographs/handouts specifically about perfect numbers and related topics

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, perfect-numbers

I am looking for books and/or monographs specifically about [*perfect numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) and related topics, where I could find proofs of results about them.

An example that I have in mind for such a book is Song Y. Yan's [Perfect, Amicable, and Sociable Numbers: A Computational Approach](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Perfect_Amicable_and_Sociable_Numbers.html?id=EwgYvHoG9uoC&redir_esc=y).

However, this book's emphasis is on amicable numbers rather than perfect numbers per se.  I was wondering if there was a book or monograph devoted specifically to the theory of perfect numbers.

*PostScript:* I found this [NEU Math Circle handout](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eknill/seminars/perfect/handout.pdf) by Oliver Knill.  I would be very interested in seeing handouts/monographs/books similar to this last one.

Comment: That link at the end is not from a Harvard seminar. It is from a meeting of the “NEU Math Circle”, where NEU = Northeastern University (another university in the Boston area) and you can look up what math circles are if you have not heard about them before.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @KCd!  I will amend.